# Auto update changed paths like Dreamweaver, Possible in Sublime Text?

Tags: plugins, text-editor, sublimetext

I recently started using Sublime Text 3, mostly for HTML and CSS and still learning the tricks.

In Dreamweaver, if I change a linked file/folder name or move it to different folder (within the project folder), it asks if all the html file containing those links should be updated and if confirmed it does updated the all the files in the project folder automatically, even the unopened files are updated! It saves a lot of time and errors.

This is the only feature I missed in Notepad++ when I used it for few projects.

Now, I am wondering if the above feature is there in Sublime Text (by default or with the help of some plug ins)?

I will greatly appreciate any helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not present in Sublime by default, nor in any plugins of which I am aware, and although it is theoretically possible to write such a plugin it would be quite computationally intensive to have the feature "live". I find it much easier to keep CSS, JS, and markup in defined directories, and not move them around after creating them :)

You have to keep in mind that Notepad++ and Sublime Text are ***text editors***, not ***IDEs***, and so don't have all of the features of giant programs like Dreamweaver that are hundreds of times their size. Their primary purpose is editing and otherwise manipulating text, and ST at least (I'm not terribly familiar with N++) has a nice plugin API for writing functions to assist with that (such as [inserting the path to a file](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/FileSystem%20Autocompletion)), and people have even been able to write much more complex plugins to do things like [linting](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter) and [code intelligence](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeCodeIntel), but things like keeping an eye on large groups of files and changing them all in response to certain events, or completely refactoring significant amounts of code, just isn't what it's designed for.